# VBA Array variable

Tags: arrays, vba, variant

The following code works well if I use `n` as a `Variant` but gives me "Run time error 13 Type mismatch" if I dim `n` as `Integer`. Are there any downsides to using the `Variant`? Any other suggestions?

```
Sub Update_Yest()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim n() As Variant

    n = Array(10, 13, 17, 20, 28, 31, 35, 38)

    For i = 0 To UBound(n)
        Debug.Print n(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Array()` returns a variant containing an array, so you can't assign the return value to an integer array.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: So is there a better way to do the assignment of the array values? One that  is more efficient than n(1) = a, n(2) = b, etc? I like the "Array()" because it has less lines and the code looks neater.

Comment: I don't think there's any real problem with using the variant array, unless you really need integer-typed values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No downside, used n as variant